# SVN - Group Restriction

Tags: svn

If I have

```
[/]
@all_users = r

[/restricted_folder]
@unauthorised_users = 
@authorised_users = rw
```

Will this successfully restrict the unauthorised users access to none and give the authorised users r/w access? I not, how can it be done?

The Documentation states

> Permissions for group members can only be extended beyond the permissions the group already has. Restricting users who are part of a group to less than their group's permissions is impossible.

Which suggests that the restriction made on the unauthorised users will not restrict them, and the extension to the authorsied users will work fine.

Comment: So...what's the question here? The documentation is addressing adding restrictions to individual user accounts via their login names, not group membership.

Comment: I made an edit to try and clarify what im asking

Comment: What type of server are you using? Are you using `http://` over Apache httpd, or `svn://` over `svnserve`? Setting anonymous user access is determined by the type of server you're using. If you're using `file://`, give yourself a dope slap, get your repository under Apache httpd or svnserve, and then tell me which server you're using.

Comment: Yeah I am using svnserve